# Mootools Request onLoadstart, onProgress do ot work in IE any version

Tags: internet-explorer, mootools, response

I made a simple test here

http://jsfiddle.net/sUJRP/10/

```
<input type="button" value="Test start" id="start" />
<br /><br /><br />


<div id="response1"></div><br />
<div id="response2"></div><br />
<div id="response3"></div>

var myRequest = new Request({
    url: 'http://fiddle.jshell.net',

    onLoadstart: function(event, xhr) {
        $('response1').set('html', 'Sending start');
    },

    onProgress: function(event, xhr) {
        $('response2').set('html', 'Progress');
    },

    onSuccess: function(event, xhr) {
        $('response3').set('html', 'All done');
    }

});


$('start').addEvent('click', function(event) {
    $$('#response1,#response2,#response3').set('html', '');
    myRequest.send();

});​
```

in all browsers you will get response for all 3 states but in all version of IE all you get is
onSuccess response.

Any suggetions?

Comment: Have you tried using `onRequest` instead of `onLoadStart`?

Comment: yes onRequest works in IE , but onProgress does not 

http://jsfiddle.net/6MEn6/1/

Comment: Most likely, IE does not support `onProgress`.